# GetAuthenticationSchemes() From HttpContext .NetCore 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am Updating an older implementation of IdentityServer to .net core 3.

In the Controllers Login method i have following

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    //..Omitted
    var viewModel = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl, context, HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationSchemes());
}
```

The GetAuthenticationSchemes() returns an

```
IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription>;
```

But this is all debricated now.
Are there any package or workaround I can do to make it work as is?
Or do I need to implement a new solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is implementation of the `Login` method taken from the master from `src\IdentityServer4\host\QuickStarts\Account` folder and `AccountController.cs`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    // build a model so we know what to show on the login page
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
    {
        // we only have one option for logging in and it's an external provider
        return RedirectToAction("Challenge", "External", new { provider = vm.ExternalLoginScheme, returnUrl });
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Maybe `GetAuthenticationSchemes()` has been deprecated.